# Deploying individual certs per site on iis using octopus

Tags: ssl, iis, octopus-deploy

Currently i have several sites hosted on an iis environment, i made self-signed certificates, saved them on octopus, created scoped variables per environment, however, whenever i make a new release all certificates on the 443 bindings on all sites are changed,

Whenever i check the release output logs i see that the change is only applied to the site i want, so i think is it more related to the ssl iis plugin on octopus, how can i configure it so each deployment only affects the scoped site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that this is a limitation of IIS, and in order to achieve this you need to require server name indication (which is a feature of iis 8+), the procedure goes like this:

on the "deploy an IIS Website step template, right on the bingings section, you can create https 443 bindings where you can specify a cert and check the "require sni" option, to automatically deploy certs per each virtual host.
[image]